# TypeError: super_shuffle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color_list'

Tags: python, random, shuffle

This is my code

```
import random
import copy

def super_shuffle(color_list):
    color_list_2 = copy.copy(color_list)
    random.shuffle(color_list_2)
    for old, new in zip(color_list, color_list_2):
        if old == new:
            return super_shuffle(color_list)
    
    return color_list_2

color1 = input("Pick a color:")
color2 = input("Pick a color:")
color3 = input("Pick a color:")
color4 = input("Pick a color:")
color5 = input("Pick a color:")
color6 = input("Pick a color:")
color_list = [color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6]

super_shuffle()
```

I am trying to get it to take your colors and shuffle them into a list, but then it comes up with this error

```
TypeError: super_shuffle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color_list'
```

I am also trying to get it so I can edit the list after the list is already shuffled

I type in some colors but when they get shuffled, it is supposed to print them, but it doesn't. It just comes up with the error. I was expecting for it to print a list of my colors shuffled, but it just errored.

Comment: What don't you understand? You defined the function with a parameter: `def super_shuffle(color_list):`. But you didn't provide a corresponding argument when you called it.

Comment: you also need to assign the result of the function to another variable if you want to use it.

Comment: Why is it supposed to print them? You have no `print()` call that would do that. Expression results are not automatically printed unless you're in an interactive REPL.

Comment: if you use `list` then you can use `color_list.copy()` instead of `copy.copy(color_list)`

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line from

`super_shuffle()`

to

`print(super_shuffle(color_list))`

To print the output of your function.

As the comments already state, you defined a function that expects one argument called `color_list`. As this argument has no default value, you have to assign it, when calling the function.